# Detect App is installation link through ad's

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, installation, apk

I want to know something very tricky if anyone knows this please explain this thing to me.

Suppose my app link is available in ad of alibaba and also in youtube ad. Now one personA install my app through alibaba ad link and personB install my app through youtube ad link. How would I know that personA install my app through youtube ad or alibaba ad? Hope you understand my question.

I want to implement this in both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to know "10 people installed through Alibab and 5 through youtube" or do you need to know "person XYZ installed via youtube".  The first is easy-  just use your ad metrics.  Or have the links go to different urls on your website that redirect to the actual app, and measure hits.

For identifying this for individual downloaders-  are they downloading APKs or downloading via Play?  For an APK download, you can build two versions of the apk, each with a different resource value stating download site.  Then at runtime you can check that resource value.  For Play-  I don't think you'll be able to do that.

Comment: "person XYZ installed via youtube" this thing I am asking. Could you please send me any reference link?